# How can I check memory usage per session on IIS?

Tags: iis, memory-management, out-of-memory, iis-6, iis-10

Is there any way not monitor memory usage per session on IIS? I've seen how to perform some analysis per site and/or per app pool, but not per session. The IIS crashed with an OutOfMemoryException and we need to find which users were consuming the most memory so we can check the activity logs of those users and and find what caused the high memory usage.

Preferably not using any paid tools, and also bonus points if it works both with IIS6 and IIS10 but that's just a plus.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is nothing mapping to "memory usage per session", and you cannot imagine a tern from nowhere. If you don't have experience on such troubleshooting, you do need paid tools or paid support services.

Comment: Can you tell me then which tool will provide me what I want? "Preferably not using any paid tools", emphasis on the "Preferably". Can you please be constructive?

Comment: Tool recommendation is off-topic here if you don't know yet. Ask Google on .NET memory profiler and you can find a lot.

Comment: As you should imagine I already did, my question was specifically on a profiler that allows for a per session analysis.

Comment: Then I say it again that there is no such "per session" analysis. All memory profilers tell how objects take up the memory space and it is your responsibility to assert whether those objects/allocations make sense or not.  Get rid of unnecessary objects or let them free up as early as possible. That's the value of profiling. Case studies like https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/walkthrough can get you started.

Comment: Thank you much man! I'll check it out.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, there is no tool to check memory usage per session on IIS.
ASP .NET applications will throw a System.OutOfMemoryException error if they cannot allocate physical memory or reserve sufficient virtual memory to meet an allocation request. By default, the addressable virtual memory space that is available is 2 GB. If this is used, the operating system can't allocate additional memory.

Another cause of the issue is if other processes on the server are using most of the ram.

You could try below troubleshooting steps:

- Connect to the machine running your web application and open up task
  manager (start->run->taskmgr). Make sure other processes are not
  using up most of the RAM on the server. If they are, close them,
  migrate your application to another machine, or increase the amount
  of RAM available. Note that ASP .NET applications will appear as the
  w3wp.exe process.
- If most of the RAM is not being used, your application pool may be limited to a small amount of memory. You can increase this amount by opening the IIS manager (start->run->inetmgr), expanding the server node on the left pane, clicking on "Application Pools", right clicking on the application pool running your application, selecting "Advanced Settings", and changing the Private Memory Limit and Virtual Memory Limit in the recycling section.
- If the w3wp.exe process is taking up more than a gigabyte of RAM, please contact technical support.

please refer below link for more detail:

[How to Troubleshoot Out of Memory Issues (System.OutOfMemoryException) in ASP.NET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2020006/how-to-troubleshoot-out-of-memory-issues-system-outofmemoryexception-i)

[Troubleshooting System.OutOfMemoryExceptions in ASP.NET](https://blogs.iis.net/webtopics/troubleshooting-system-outofmemoryexceptions-in-asp-net)

Comment: Thank you very much, it's actually the w3wp.exe process that is taking most of the RAM (14GB out of 16GB), the private and virtual memory limits are correctly set but the OS cannot allocate more memory.

Comment: did you try to use some troubleshooting step mentioned in post and link?

Comment: yes, I believe the issue has to do with fragmentation of the heap, still not closer to solving it though